# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 6 and trying to render a page,I am getting the following error Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.I have tried all the options I could find in Stack Overflow.

Here are the options

1) Include FormsModule in app.module.ts in the imports

2) Used [(ngModel)] in the html file.

3) Changed the version number of  "@angular/http": "^6.0.0" to different versions like  "@angular/http": "^6.0.1" and other 6 versions

*.component.html

```
<div [@routerTransition]>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Program Name <input [(ngModel)]="programName" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{programName}}" /></th>
            <th>Start Date   <input [(ngModel)]="startDate" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{startDate}}" /></th>
            <th>End Date <input [(ngModel)]="endDate" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{endDate}}" /></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Category Name</th>
          <th>Max Points</th>
          <th>Max Score</th>
          <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let program of programCategorys; let i = index">
          <td>
              <input [(ngModel)]="program.categoryName" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{program.categoryName}}" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input [(ngModel)]="program.maxPoints" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{program.maxPoints}}" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input [(ngModel)]="program.maxScore" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{program.maxScore}}" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <button class="btn btn-default"  type="button" (click)="deleteFieldValue(i)">Delete</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newAttributeCode" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.categoryName" name="newAttributeCode" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newAttributeName" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.maxPoints" name="newAttributeName" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newAttributePrice" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.maxScore" name="newAttributePrice" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="addFieldValue()">+</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="container" >
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-3"  >
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="pgSave()">Save</button>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"  >
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="pgSubmit()">Submit</button>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"  >
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="pgCancel()">Cancel</button>

    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export const createTranslateLoader = (http: HttpClient) => {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [AuthGuard],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I am using Visual Studio Code,I am getting the error when I click on a particular link.Please guide me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you imported `FormsModule` in `app.module.ts` ?

Comment: Yes I have used.

Comment: Kindly include your `app.module.ts` file as well. Also, is there any error reported on bootstrap of the application?

Comment: Included the app.module.ts also

Comment: put the input in a form tag

Comment: Included form tag in input it does not work..

Comment: Could you please make a working snippet here: https://stackblitz.com/ . It will be easier to spot the error and to help

Comment: Can you show us the *.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by using ng-model instead of [(ngModel)]..